# UICollectionViewCell size is not same on iPhone 11 and iPhone 11 Pro Max

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a vertical `UICollectionView`. Its first cell is horizontal UICollectionView with a fullwidth cell. My problem is that when I lunch the app on iPhone 11 everything is ok, but in the case of iPhone 11 ProMax, the cell is not fullwidth. I also override `sizeForItemAt` where I' returning `CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 238`). The collectionView width is equal to `self.view.frame.width`

[this is iPhone 11 screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSxnI.png)

[this one is iPhone 11 Pro Max screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JY4ux.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Add some images or screenshots of what you've implemented so far & what is the required functionality.

Comment: From your second screenshot, it seems like the problem is not the cell, but collection view itself. Make suere collection view's frame fills th width of it's superview.

Comment: Can you share how and where are you setting the collectionview width? It might be at that time you are setting it the frame is not calculated correctly, why not to setup the collectionview with autolayout by using anchors? Like collection.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true. And so on for trailingAnchor, topAnchor and bottomAnchor.

Comment: @denis_lor I've made it from the storyboard and it is fullwidth

Comment: I've solved the problem. the reason was custom flowlayout. I've changed it to default and it works correctly. thanks guys for advice